# How to run/compile asp.net codes, stored in database table?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I'm looking a way to run codes provided as a string...

Example: I want to store some asp.net c# codes in a database table and I would like to run it on a page.

For example:

```
string codesFromDBTable = "Response.Write(abc)" //something like that...
```

Is that possible?

Answer (score 3):

Sure, it's possible using [CSharpCodeProvider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.csharp.csharpcodeprovider%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). But I can't stress enough how careful you should be executing arbitrary code from any source...

You might want to consider isolating the code you compile and execute into a separate AppDomain and limit the privileges available to it.

What exactly is your use case?

Answer (score 1):

Is something like this what you are looking for?

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9019/Compiling-and-Executing-Code-at-Runtime